# Bitwise & and I

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

[Why is 1 & 4 = 0](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/lnxpcomp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xlcpp8l.doc/language/ref/bitande.htm)

whereas
[1 | 4 evaluates to 5](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/lnxpcomp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xlcpp8l.doc/language/ref/bitande.htm)

Comment: Can you explain your reasoning on how you expected to get 12?

Comment: my bad..did a mistake in calculation. I get it now.

Comment: @Mysticial something like this: `1 & 100 = 1100`

Comment: The `&` operator doesn't glue byte strings together. See the answers below.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well.. because.

For `&`, the `AND` operator:

```
0001       = 1
0100       = 4
---- (AND)
0000       = 0
```

for `|`, the `OR` operator:

```
0001       = 1
0100       = 4
---- (OR)
0101       = 5
```

Answer (score 3):

Bitwise & => If both bits are higher, then the output is higher else output is zero.

```
0 0 1
1 0 0
-----
0 0 0  => 0   // 1 & 1 = 1 , 1 & 0 = 0
```

Now try yourself Bitwise `|`. Any of the bit is higher, output is higher.

Answer (score 2):

`1` is `0b001`, and `4` is `0b100`, so, naturally, `1&4` is `0b000` and `1|4` is `0b101`, which is `5`.

Answer (score 2):

Look at it in binary form.

1d(ecimal) = 001b(inary)

4d(ecimal) = 100b(inary)

thus

```
001b
100b & (both bits have to be 1 to yield 1)
--
000b = 0d
```

and

```
001b
100b | (only one on either side (or both) has to be 1 to yield 1)
--
101b = 5d
```